# Java heap space exception when trying to fill a list

Tags: java, list, exception

I'm writing a program in java and i need to make a list whose nodes are another list . My code for the nodes of the sub list is this :

```
public class Page {

    private String word;
    private int num;

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public Page(String word, int num) {
        this.word = word;
        this.num = num;
    }

}
```

My code for the nodes of my main list is :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IndPage {
    private ArrayList<Page> Eggrafi;
    //private ArrayList<Page> Eggrafi = new ArrayList<Page>();

    public IndPage(String name, int bytes) {
        Eggrafi = new ArrayList<Page>();
        Eggrafi.add(new Page(name, bytes));
    }

    public ArrayList<Page> getEggrafi() {
        return Eggrafi;
    }

    public void setEggrafi(ArrayList<Page> eggrafi) {
        Eggrafi = eggrafi;
    }

}
```

When i use in my main the following code to fill my list i get a java heap space exception:

```
if(Index.size()!=0){
                            for(int j=0;j<Index.size();j++){
                                for(int y=0;y<Index.get(j).getEggrafi().size();y++){
                                    if((Index.get(j).getEggrafi().get(y).getWord()).equals(tokens[i-1])){
                                        Index.get(j).getEggrafi().add(new Page(fileName[k],byte_count));
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Index.add(new IndPage(fileName[k],byte_count));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            Index.add(new IndPage(fileName[k],byte_count));
                        }
```

Also my main list is declared this way :

```
List<IndPage> Index = new ArrayList<IndPage>();
```

I've tried many things but still getting the java heap space exception .

Comment: Declaring "private ArrayList<Page> Eggrafi;" two times and initializing it two times (in class and in constructor).

Comment: I'm sorry the private ArrayList<Page> Eggrafi = new ArrayList<Page>();
was in comments .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in your for loop:

```
for(int j=0;j<Index.size();j++){
   for(int y=0;y<Index.get(j).getEggrafi().size();y++){
     if((Index.get(j).getEggrafi().get(y).getWord()).equals(tokens[i-1])){
        Index.get(j).getEggrafi().add(new Page(fileName[k],byte_count));
     }
     else{
      Index.add(new IndPage(fileName[k],byte_count));
    }
  }
}
```

Your for loops are doing a check against the lists .size() function you are adding new items to those lists, so the .size() will always be at least 1 more than either the j or y index variables and the loops will never terminate.  That eventually is running you out of heap space.  The Index.size() and Index.get(j).getEggrafi().size() values are recalculated each time by the for loop, they are not cached.

Answer (score 2):

I think you code is allocating a new list for every insert.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IndPage {
    private List<Page> Eggrafi = new ArrayList<Page>();

    public IndPage(final String name, final int bytes) {
        Eggrafi.add(new Page(name, bytes));
    }

    public List<Page> getEggrafi() {
        return Eggrafi;
    }

    public void setEggrafi(final List<Page> eggrafi) {
        Eggrafi = eggrafi;
    }

}
```

The code for the loops can be improved by using Java 5 style collection loops ie:

```
for (final Page page : Eggrafi) {
    ...
}
```